# Get the pixel values from cv::Mat as numbers?

Tags: c++, image, opencv, pixel, mat

**Hello,**

I'm quite new to OpenCV **and** C++ so I really don't know what is going on here. I searched for a way to access the pixel values of a Mat image (of type CV_8UC3) and found this:

```
Vec3b bgrPixel = foo.at<Vec3b>(Point(x, y));
//bgrPixel.val[0] is B, bgrPixel.val[1] is G, bgrPixel.val[2] is R
```

But this outputs chars instead of ints, when I do `cout << bgrPixel.val[0] << endl;` for instance, it gives some really strange characters:

```
r
Ç
è
Ç
~
ö
É
è
ÿ
×
×
;
2
#
2
/
+
'
"
)
%
-
*
```

How can I get the pixel values as ints? Or is there a simpler way to access them, e.g. by converting the Mat to a regular array (like you would in Python)?

*Thanks for the answers in advance!*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use: `cout << (int)(bgrPixel.val[0]) << endl;`

`bgrPixel.val[0]` is of type `unsigned char`, and it is printed as character.

Casting from `unsigned char` to `int` solves the problem.

Comment: Thanks. I know this question sounds really dumb, but as I said, I don't have much experience with the system.